# Run Security Scan on a website search form

Tags: security, coldfusion

I need to run a security scan on my site. When the scan hits my search page where the user selects 1-5 states and any number of checkboxes before the submit of the page. This page slows the security scan down by hours into days. 
Any thoughts on how to optimize a form based web page to increase the speed of a security scan.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. What is the security scan attempting todo that slows it down? What is the security scan tool you are using? May we see a copy of the HTML code for the form? Are you following good security practices and validating input on client side with regex patterns and of coarse again validating input on server side?

Comment: What are you using for the Security Scan and what is it scanning for?

Comment: we are trying to figure out is there any way to optimize the page...the scan runs for each state and the 20 checkboxes, so the number of times this page has to run to test all situations is taking a long time...is there anything we can do to the page to help speed up whatever scan software we use, or is it all about configuring the scan software....

Comment: What about the checkboxes is being checked? If you remove the checkboxes, does the scan complete or is it some other part of the page that's causing issues? With 50 states and 20 checkboxes, that's only 1000 iterations. And if it can check 20 boxes for 1 state, why does it need to check for the other 49, also? Do they stay the same or change based on state? It may be a scan software issue, also, if it can't recognize if they are the same.